# Возникли проблемы при компиляции

Tags: c, указатели

Пишет следующую ошибку - "lvalue required as increment operand".

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *p[];

int main(){

    p[0] = "12345";
    p[1] = "qwerty";
    p[2] = "l1l3433";

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        printf("%s\n", *++p); /* здесь ошибка */
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Объясните, пожалуйста, почему?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы определили массив с именем `p`, а изменять идентификатор, являющийся именем массива, вы не можете. Имя массива всегда остается именем массива - это не указатель...

Вы бы могли написать

```
char **p;
```

и оно бы скомпилировалось. Но не работало бы. Как не работал бы и ваш код, даже если бы имя массива считалось lvalue - потому что вы объявляете массив с неизвестным количеством элементов.

Можно исправить ситуацию:

```
char *p[] =  {"12345","qwerty","l1l3433"};


int main(){

    int i;
    char**pp = p;
    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        printf("%s\n", *++pp);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Но тут вопрос: вы сначала *увеличиваете* указатель, а только потом разыменовываете... Вы верно просите вывести только 2 элемента, так что за границы не выходите, но вы хотите вывести именно вторую и третью строки? Если да - то все верно, но если первую и вторую - то `++pp` надо заменить на `pp++`.

Comment: Все верно, вторую и третью. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте `*++p` на `**(++p)`. 
Я подозреваю, что компилятор пробует оператором "*" декодировать значение "++", что невозможно, так как "++" - не указатель.

ДОБАВЛЕНО: "*p[]" - это вроде указатель на указатель.

Comment: если написать **(++p), то будет выводиться символ, а это не совсем то, что мне надо.

Comment: Вас понял, извините.